# Find the angular speed of the smaller gear?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

[image: Linakge]

1.Why does the angular speed of small gear depend only on that of the larger gear?

2.Why does the length of linkage connecting the two gears not have any influence on the angular speed of smaller gear?

The first question can be answered by looking at slack and tightening of chain caused by rotation of the linkage.

Can someone please help to find the answer to the second question?

Comment: "Why does the length of linkage connecting two gears does not have any influence on the angular speed of smaller gear?"  I think you could argue this isn't even a valid question.  More importantly though; what are your thoughts; what have you tried for an answer?  We are here for conceptual help; but that's hard if we don't know what concepts give you trouble.

Comment: Since the end of the linkage is glued to center of the small  gear , centre of gear has the same velocity as the end of the linkage.But angular velocity of small gear is dependent only on Radius of large non-rotating gear.
Usually for pure rolling on ground, Vcenter=RxW I am asking if such relationship exists here.

Comment: +1 A thought-provoking problem. Possibly Mathematics SE (geometry) or Engineering SE would be more suitable. ... Your 2 questions appear to be the same. The answer to the 1st question should also answer the 2nd. What is your answer to the 1st question? ... Also, can you post an image of the full question?

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear what you mean by the angular speed of the linkage.

If you're saying that the whole system is rotating around some axis parallel to the two axes of the gears, then to find the angular speed of any of the two gears in the resting lab frame, you can first determine each gear's angular speed in the rest frame of the system, then add the rotation of the system (paying attention to signs).

If by linkage you mean the chain, then first of all there is no obvious axis about which you might consider the chain's angular speed. You can pick any. Having picked such an axis, each small section of the chain will have its own angular speed, which will change over time.

The easiest way to grasp how a system of two gears and a chain works, is to notice that in a taut chain, the speed is constant throughout. So if you know the angular velocity $\omega_1$ and radius $r_1$ of the first pulley, then the chain's speed is $v=r_1 \omega_1$, and so if the second pulley has radius $r_2$, then its angular velocity will be:

$$ \omega_2 = \frac{v}{r_2} = \omega_1 \frac{r_1}{r_2} $$

As you can see from this equation, the angular velocities are inversely proportional to the radii. So if $r_1>r_2$ then $\omega_2>\omega_1$ and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, its "length of the linkage".Here the video of the whole mechanism. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_d10ytEbzXI

Comment: Well, ok, but does my post not answer your question? The length of the chain makes no difference, as long as it is taut and inextensible. The speed of the chain is the same throughout.

Comment: Here chain is not moving along the gear.The larger gear is not rotating.

Comment: Thank You ,Can you do the analysis from a ground frame only?I would like to know what arguments are required to drive the same equation from rest frame.

Comment: @kuku I would basically refer to sammy gerbil's answer and my second paragraph: It is generally easiest to start in the rest frame $S$ of the linkage, and then to add the rotation of the linkage. In this case, if $\omega_1$ is the angular velocity of the large gear relative to the linkage, then, as the gear is stationary in the lab frame $S'$, the linkage rotates at $\Omega = -\omega_1$, so we have:

Comment: @kuku I would basically refer to sammy gerbil's answer and my second paragraph: It is generally easiest to start in the rest frame $S$ of the linkage, and then to add the rotation of the linkage. In this case, if $\omega_1$ is the angular velocity of the large gear relative to the linkage, then, as the gear is stationary in the lab frame $S'$, the linkage rotates at $\Omega = -\omega_1$, so we have, in the lab frame:

$$ \omega_2' = \omega_2 + \Omega= \omega_1 \frac{r_1}{r_2} + \Omega = \Omega \left( 1 - \frac{r_1}{r_2} \right) $$

Answer (score 0):

**Note :** After writing this answer (for which reason I am reluctant to delete it), I can now see that it is the same as @Surfcello's answer, which was posted earlier so it deserves the credit.

---

The [video link which you provide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_d10ytEbzXI) shows the connecting rod EG rotating about axis E while the inner wheel remains stationary. During this motion the outer wheel rotates about E and also about its own centre G.

The belt does not slip against either wheel. It rotates around both wheels. But it is not obvious in the ground frame of reference how the rotation of the linkage EG affects the rotation of the outer wheel.

Suppose in the ground frame (which is also the frame of the stationary inner wheel) the linkage EG is rotating anti-clockwise with angular speed $\Omega$. In a frame which is rotating with EG, the inner wheel is rotating clockwise with angular speed $\Omega$. The length of the belt between the two wheels remains fixed, so the points of contact on the two wheels move with the same linear speed. The **clockwise** angular speed $\omega'$ of the outer wheel **in the rotating frame** is therefore given by $$\Omega R=\omega' r$$ where $R, r$ are the two radii.

However, in the ground frame the outer wheel makes one complete revolution **anti-clockwise** if it remains stationary relative to the linkage EG whenever EG rotates by one full circle about E. So in the ground frame of reference the angular speed of the outer wheel is $$\omega = \omega'- \Omega = (\frac{R}{r}-1)\Omega$$ If the outer wheel is the larger $(r > R)$ then it will rotate in the opposite direction to the linkage EG. If the two wheels are the same size $(r=R)$ then the outer wheel does not rotate while the linkage EG rotates. (This happens, for example, when you rotate an elastic band or loop of string between two fingers by moving one around the other. The band or string does not slip against your fingers, neither do your fingers rotate about their own axes. The length of the band or string makes no difference.)

The length of the linkage EG does not affect the angular speed $\omega'$ of the outer wheel in the rotating frame of reference. And it does not affect the angular speed $\Omega$ of the linkage, which is what connects the rotation rates in the two frames of reference. So it has no effect on the angular speed of the outer wheel.

Comment: Good analogy using finger and elastic bands.